# Getting AWS Instance limits via console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

On the limit page at any region in aws ec2 service there are limits for instances i can create:

```
aws gamelift describe-ec2-instance-limits --query 'EC2InstanceLimits[].{EC2InstanceType:EC2InstanceType,InstanceLimit:InstanceLimit}' --region us-east-1 --output text
```

Above command is near the thing i need. Output looking like:

```
r3.8xlarge  2
m3.xlarge   15
m4.10xlarge 1
c4.large    20
r3.xlarge   15
r3.large    20
m4.xlarge   15
m4.2xlarge  10
t2.small    20
c3.4xlarge  5
t2.large    20
c4.4xlarge  5
c3.xlarge   15
c4.xlarge   15
m3.2xlarge  10
c4.2xlarge  10
r3.2xlarge  10
m3.medium   20
t2.micro    20
c3.2xlarge  10
c3.large    20
m3.large    20
m4.large    20
c4.8xlarge  2
m4.4xlarge  5
c3.8xlarge  2
t2.medium   20
r3.4xlarge  5
```

What i need is to get a list of all instance types that are available for region to create. At this page: https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-east-1#Limits:, you can see a table with Instance Limits header, that has Name and Current Limit columns. I need to get a full list of Instance Type and its Current Limit, so i can create instances using this information.

Like:

```
r3.8xlarge 5
c3.4xlarge 10 
c4.8xlarge 0
```

etc(all instances), meaning i can create right now in this region 5 instances of r3.8xlarge, 10 instances of c3.4xlarge and 0 of c4.8xlarge.

Answer (score 0):

The `aws gamelift describe-ec2-instance-limits` command is very useful because it displays:

- Maximum number of instances allowed per AWS account (service limit)
- Current usage level for the AWS account

However, that API call is only available in regions that offer the Amazon GameLift service.

Even though the information is displayed in the Amazon EC2 Management Console, there is no Amazon EC2 API call available to obtain the same information.

**Update:** Limits are now available via the [Service Quotas](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/06/introducing-service-quotas-view-and-manage-quotas-for-aws-services-from-one-location/) interface.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The gamelift api seems to return some limits related to gamelift, not true account limits as reported on ec2 console page. see https://i.imgur.com/6LAqlTK.png vs the API returns: `||  0               |  m4.large         |  20             ||`

Comment: gamelift also skips newer instance types like c5* .