# How to get max-instances for each instance-type by aws cli?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli

The max numbers of launching instances are described on [EC2 Service Limits](https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home#Limits) of AWS console, and you can see the value of `max-instances` for each instance type.

On the other hand, by using `aws ec2 describe-account-attributes`, it's possible to get the value of `max-instances` for overall, but it doesn't include `max-instances` for each (or specific) instance type.

Is it possible to get `max-instances` for each instance type by using aws cli?

p.s. I checked [Getting AWS Instance limits via console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44509068/getting-aws-instance-limits-via-console) <s>but it seems talking about [GameLift](https://aws.amazon.com/gamelift/).</s> and it sounds work well, however, the result is not the same as what AWS web console shows. [→log](https://gist.github.com/otiai10/70a41a1a967d727d790d6b296c07b73b)

Comment: That other question is actually the same question you're asking, here.  They wanted to find the EC2 limits and were showing the gamelift option by contrast.  John Rotenstein answered that question, correctly as far as I can tell -- there is no ec2 API for this, but in regions where gamelift is deployed, it appears that you can get the ec2 answer from the gamelift API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting AWS Instance limits via console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44509068/getting-aws-instance-limits-via-console)

Comment: Thanks. I just tried the command introduced in that question and saw the result is different from what displayed on the web console. For more details https://gist.github.com/otiai10/70a41a1a967d727d790d6b296c07b73b . At the same time, I've found https://gist.github.com/sebsto/468670c7c0d5feeade69 I'm gonna try it.

Comment: Interesting on both counts.  I would suggest that if you find a viable workaround, you might post its details as an answer to the other question, because this one may be closed as a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 0):

New answer for an old question...

There is now a [Service Quotas](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/06/introducing-service-quotas-view-and-manage-quotas-for-aws-services-from-one-location/) service:

> With **Service Quotas**, you can view and manage your quotas easily and at scale as your AWS workloads grow. Quotas, also referred to as limits, are the maximum number of resources that you can create in an AWS account. AWS implements quotas to provide highly available and reliable service to all customers, and protect you from unintentional spend. Each quota starts with an AWS default value. Based on your needs, you can request to increase quota values for your specific account.